# MySQL, PHP and AS3 - showing content depending on ID

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash

I am using Flash CC to create an interactive map with a lot of information for particular sites. I am using MySQL and PHP to retrieve the information and then display it in flash. I am trying to dynamically change the site ID and then change the data displayed in flash.

I created a function on the frame, as well as link the package.

My PHP Code:

```
$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUser = "username";
$dbPass = "password";
$dbName = "dbname";
$dbTable = "tablename";

if (isset($_GET['sn'])) {
    $sn = $_GET['sn'];
    }

// connecting and selecting database
@mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass) or die(mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db($dbName) or die(mysql_error());

// getting data
$data = "";
$datatitle = "";
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$dbTable." WHERE Site_ID='$sn'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
    $data .= strip_tags($row->Site_Description);
    $datatitle .= $row->Site_Name;
}
die($data);
```

This is my action script package:
package {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent

public class App extends MovieClip {
    public static const URL:String = 'http://weburl/get.php';

    private var _loader:URLLoader;
    private var _request:URLRequest;

    public function App():void {
        output(" ");
        loadData();
    }

    public function onLoadData(e:Event):void {
        output( e.target.data);
    }
    private function onDataFiledToLoad(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
        output("onDataFiledToLoad error=" + e.text);
    }
    public function output(str:String):void {
        var text:String = field.text;
        field.text = str + "\n" + text;
    }

}

}
```

My Code on Frame 1

```
function loadData():void {
internal var siteNumber = 2;

next_site30.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler30n); 
function mouseDownHandler30n(event:MouseEvent):void 
{ siteNumber = siteNumber + 1;
    trace(siteNumber);

}

output(" ");

var randomParam:String = "?p=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (10000000)) + "&sn=";
_loader = new URLLoader();
_request = new URLRequest(URL + randomParam + siteNumber);
_request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
_loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadData);
_loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
_loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.NETWORK_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
_loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.VERIFY_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
_loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.DISK_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
_loader.load(_request);             
stop();     
}
```

At the moment, the siteNumber is increasing, but not being applied to the URL. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried the links below and they have not helped.

[MySQL,PhP, and Flash As3 Data is not loading properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545198/mysql-php-and-flash-as3-data-is-not-loading-properly)

[loading images and data from mysql into Flash using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485962/loading-images-and-data-from-mysql-into-flash-using-php)

[Load images to a TileList from Mysql using PHP and XML on Flash CS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491037/load-images-to-a-tilelist-from-mysql-using-php-and-xml-on-flash-cs5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the code on frame one (now only contains the button):

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
next_site30.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler30n); 
            function mouseDownHandler30n(event:MouseEvent):void 
            { siteNumber = siteNumber + 1;
                trace(siteNumber);
                loadData();
            }
prev_site30.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler30prev); 
            function mouseDownHandler30prev(event:MouseEvent):void 
            { siteNumber = siteNumber - 1;
                trace(siteNumber);
                loadData();
            }
```

And this is the package Actionscript code:

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent

public class App extends MovieClip {
    public static const URL:String = 'http://leonoravirtual.designsensetest.net.au/get.php';

    private var _loader:URLLoader;
    private var _request:URLRequest;
    public function App():void {
        output(" ");
        loadData();
    }
    var siteNumber:int = 2;

    public function loadData():void {
        output(" ");

        var randomParam:String = "?p=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (10000000)) + "&sn=";
        _loader = new URLLoader();
        _request = new URLRequest(URL + randomParam + siteNumber);
        _request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadData);
        _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
        _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.NETWORK_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
        _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.VERIFY_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
        _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.DISK_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
        _loader.load(_request);
    }  

    public function onLoadData(e:Event):void {
        output( e.target.data);
    }
    private function onDataFiledToLoad(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
        output("onDataFiledToLoad error=" + e.text);
    }
    public function output(str:String):void {
        var text:String = field.text;
        field.text = str + text;
    }

 }

}
```

This worked :)